# Algorithm for minimum weight matching with "tree topology"

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, matching-theory

Given a finite graph $G(V,E)$ with undirected and weighted edges, whose set of vertices $V$ is partitioned into a collection $\mathfrak{P}=\lbrace V_1,\,\dots,\,V_k\rbrace$ of non-empty and pairwise disjoint subsets of $V$.

**Question:**
what is the complexity of determining a matching of size $k-1$ and minimal weight such that

- every set in $\mathfrak{P}$ has an element that is matched
- every edge in the matching is adjacent to elements from two sets in $\mathfrak{P}$
- the matching edges resemble a spanning tree of the sets in $\mathfrak{P}$